# Django: Can't add field to custom user model

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

So, I've got a well running Django 3 app with a custom user model running on a MySQl db. I've been doing makemigrations and migrate successfully for months.  Today I tried to add a field to my custom User Model called Account.  The second I add a field to that model, the dev server attempts to process the change and crashes with this error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'account_account.lifetimeuser' in 'field list'")

Doesn't matter the type of the field or the name.

The base exception is:
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'account_account.lifetimeuser' in 'field list'")

Understand that this is NOT at runtime.  It's right after I change the model and stop typing. Or in this case uncomment the lifetimeuser field (BTW, this is for testing only.  I know I have an is_lifetime_user.  That's the real field that was added sometime ago.

Also note that this is ONLY with the Account model.  Every other model in the file works as expected.  Add, remove, edit: no problem as long as the syntax is correct.

Since the error happens immediately, I can't makemigrations or migrate.  I know my DB is in sync everywhere else.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what is going on here?  Is there some DB setting I'm missing?
Thanks!

Here's the model in case that helps.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=None, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_index=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    access_level = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_freeuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_10kuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_100kuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_lifetimeuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #lifetimeuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    force_pw_change = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_joined']

    # this is the field the user will use to login
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    # tell the account what AcctManager to use
    objects = MyAccountManager()
```

A couple updates:
I went through the settings and commented out each line of middleware to see what happened when I uncomment the test field in the account model.  No change.

Also, I experimented with models in the same model.py file and the test server notices the change and says reloading, and reloads successfully.  It's only for the account model that this fails. Account model also says reloading but fails. Very strange.

Comment: #lifetimeuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)  the field is commented out

Comment: I know.  As I said above, the minute I uncomment it the error is produced.  That is the question...Why?

Comment: try to comment out AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py, make migration and then uncomment it back

Comment: Thanks for trying to help...Comment out AUTH_USER_MODEL and test: same behavior.  The second I uncomment the field, the error happens.